# Create variable to reuse in firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In a complex product, you often has to use the same rule conditions, for example if a user is admin:

```
match /games/{game} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
}
match /locations/{location} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
}
```

Is there a way to store the condition inside a variable to reuse it (instead of write it every time)? For example:

```
const isAdmin = request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;    

match /games/{game} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if isAdmin
}
match /locations/{location} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if isAdmin
}
```

I have no idea what's the language behind the firestore rules and what kind of assets I am able to use.

Comment: If you want to learn more about the syntax for security rules, you should start with the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Custom Functions, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0#custom_functions).

In your case it would be something along the following lines (untested):

```
function isAdmin() {
  return request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true;    
}
match /games/{game} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if isAdmin();
}
match /locations/{location} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if isAdmin();
}
```

---

Note that the position of a function within the Security Rule "hierarchy" is important. Have a look at this [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=6) for more details.